# Codeigniter cannot display image but instead prompts me to download something

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, get

I have the following code which works in my other controller:

```
public function get_image(){
    $filename = $this->input->get('path');
    $handle = fopen($filename, "rb"); 
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); 
    fclose($handle); 
    
    header("content-type: image"); 
    
    echo $contents; 
}
```

[image]

However, when I implemented the same code into another controller it is not showing me the image that I wanted but instead it is prompting me to download a certain file.

[image]

This what the file contains

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

class Pahiram_Post extends CI_Controller {
    
    private $STATUS_AVAILABLE = 'available';
    private $STATUS_UNAVAILABLE = 'unavailable';
    private $STATUS_RENTING = 'renting';
    private $STATUS_REQUESTING = 'requesting';
    private $STATUS_DEACTIVATED = 'deactivated';


    #function __constructor() {
    #    parent::__constructor();
    #}


    function create_post() {

        if($this->input->post() > 0){
            $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');

            $path = $this->input->post('path');
            unset($_POST['path']);

            if($this->Pahiram_Post_Model->insert()){
                $this->output->set_status_header('201');

                $new_path = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->insert_image_location($path);

                $this->upload_image($path, $new_path);
            }
            else{
                $this->output->set_status_header('409');
            }

            echo json_encode($this->input->post());
        }

    }
    


    public function upload_image($path, $new_path){
        if (!copy($path, $new_path)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function get_image(){
        $filename = $this->input->get('path');
        $handle = fopen($filename, "rb"); 
        $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename)); 
        fclose($handle); 
        
        header("content-type: image"); 
        
        echo $contents; 
    }

    public function get_post() {

        $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');

        $data = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->get_post();

        echo json_encode($data[0]);
    }

    function set_post_available($post_id) { 
        $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');
        $status_code = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->set_status($post_id, $this->STATUS_AVAILABLE);
        $this->output->set_status_header($status_code);
    }

    function set_post_unavailable($post_id) {
        $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');
        $status_code = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->set_status($post_id, $this->STATUS_UNAVAILABLE);
        $this->output->set_status_header($status_code);
    }

    function set_post_renting($post_id) {
        $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');
        $status_code = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->set_status($post_id, $this->STATUS_RENTING);
        $this->output->set_status_header($status_code);
    }

    function set_post_requesting($post_id) {
        $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');
        $status_code = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->set_status($post_id, $this->STATUS_REQUESTING);
        $this->output->set_status_header($status_code);
    }

    function deactivate_post($post_id) {
        $this->load->model('Pahiram_Post_Model');
        $status_code = $this->Pahiram_Post_Model->set_status($post_id, $this->STATUS_DEACTIVATED);
        $this->output->set_status_header($status_code);
    }

}
```

Comment: Presumable, somewhere, a Content-Disposition header is being set to "attachment". Can you share the code for the controller that has the problem, rather than the code that works as expected?

Comment: @rickdenhaan i edited the it and attached the code im trying to debug

Answer (score 0):

So this is very weird but it did work so I was looking for answers in the net and then suddenly I saw this one https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/image-is-being-thrown-as-a-white-blank-image

User snapey said that it could be a stray whitespace and in fact the code that i just provided do have a whitespace before <?Php. So i proceeded to delete that whitespace and it just magically work. Still bugs me why that happens.